# How do I pass different values based on array item type to the same prop in child component

Tags: reactjs, arrays, typescript, react-props

In my React/TypeScript component I have an array of items (objects). The can be items of type `ItemOne` or `ItemTwo` . These items differ in the `createdDate` and `broadcastDate` field.

How do I pass or `createdDate` -> `item.createdDate` or `broadcastDate` -> `item. broadcastDate` to the child `<Item date={} />` component *date* prop?

What's the best approach here?

**Parent component:**

```
type ItemOne = {
    title: string;
    createdDate?: Date | undefined;
    type: One
}

type ItemTwo = {
    title: string;
    broadcastDate?: Date | undefined;
    type: Two
}

type Props = {
  items: (ItemOne | ItemTwo)[];
};

const MyParent = ({ items }: Props) => {

  return items?.length ? (
    <div>
      <ul>
        {items.map((item) => (
          <Item date={item. // <- how get here the correct value} title={item.title} />
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  ) : null;
};

export default Parent;
```

**Update:**
I got it working using this approach, *cast* `item` to the proper type using `as`:

```
 {items.map((item) => {
          if (item.type === 'One') {
            const itemOne = item as ItemOne;
            return (
              <Item
                key={itemOne.uuid}
                date={itemOne.broadcastDate?.timestamp!}
                title={itemOne.title}
                url={anotherFunction(itemOne.url)}
              />
            );
          }
          if (item.type === 'Two') {
            const itemTwo = item as ItemTwo;
            return (
              <Item
                key={itemTwo.id}
                date={articleItem.createdDate?.timestamp!}
                title={item.title}
                url={customFunction(articleItem.url)}
              />
            );
          }
          return null;
        })}
```

Or is there a cleaner way to do this so I don't have to copy over the jsx?

Comment: how about `date={item.createdDate ?? item.broadcastDate}` or even `||` would do

Comment: @Thomas typescript doesn't know about `createdDate` and `broadcastDate` at this moment: Property 'createdDate' does not exist on type. I updated my question with a working example. Do you have a suggestion to improve that?

Comment: `item.type === "One" ? item.createdDate : item.broadcastDate`

Answer (score 1):

you can use typescripts discriminated union feature along with their type field. Something like this:

```
type ItemType = 'One' | 'Two';

type ItemOne = {
    title: string;
    createdDate?: Date | undefined;
    type: ItemType;
}

type ItemTwo = {
    title: string;
    broadcastDate?: Date | undefined;
    type: ItemType;
}

type Props = {
  items: (ItemOne | ItemTwo)[];
};

const MyParent = ({ items }: Props) => {

  const getDate = (item: ItemOne | ItemTwo): Date | undefined => {
    switch (item.type) {
      case 'One':
        return (item as ItemOne).createdDate;
      case 'Two':
        return (item as ItemTwo).broadcastDate;
    }
  };

  return items?.length ? (
    <div>
      <ul>
        {items.map((item) => (
          <Item date={getDate(item)} title={item.title} />
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  ) : null;
};

export default MyParent;
```